# XML parsing: line 1, character 345, duplicate attribute

Tags: sql-server

I am trying to get the particular attribute value from XML column, but I'm getting an error

> XML parsing: line 1, character 345, duplicate attribute

My code:

```
select 
    ship_to_cust_num,
    tank_num,
    tank_capacity_qty,
    tank_pkg_type_code,
    COALESCE(REPLACE(CAST(CAST(b.tank_inspection AS NTEXT) AS XML).value('(/TankInspection/Questions/Question[@AASAQno="9"]/@QAns)[1]', 'VARCHAR(50)'), '#', ''), 0)
from 
    bulk_site_tank (nolock)b
where 
    convert(varchar, b.tank_inspection) != 'NULL'
```

Comment: Kindly let me advise why this error is occurring as I am not able to find the root cause in MSDN.

Comment: Do not `NTEXT` cause it's deprecated.

Comment: A few questions first: Why are you using `ntext`, it's been deprecated since 2005? Why are you using `NOLOCK`, and why without the `WITH` keyword (not using the `WITH` keyword on table hints is also deprecated). `!= NULL` won't work, unless you have `ANSI_NULLS` off, which is, again, deprecated. Also, you aren't declaring your length for the `varchar` in your `CONVERT`, which *can* (will) result in unexpected behaviour. There's a lot of problems with this code, which needs addressing first. If there's a reason for using these, then do let us know. Thanks

Comment: Also, in regards to the error, we don't have access to your data, so we can't see the value of `b.tank_inspection`. You'll need to provide sample data that **replicates** the issue, otherwise we can only guess I'm afraid.

Comment: I have changed  Cast to Convert but getting same error

Comment: You may wish to take a look at the XML documents in your `tank_inspection` column. One or more may be badly formed and contain an element with, well, a duplicate attribute.

Comment: `CAST` and `CONVERT` do the same thing, @MaheshB. Changing a `CAST` to a `CONVERT` won't change things here.

Answer (score 1):

The simple answer is that the error is telling you the problem. But to explain further. Take this simple statement:

```
DECLARE @xml varchar(MAX);

SET @XML = '
<root>
    <child>
        <element attribute="1">value</element>
        <element attribute="2" attribute="2">Another Value</element>
    </child>
</root>';

SELECT *
FROM (VALUES(CONVERT(xml, @XML)))V(X);
```

If you run that, you'll get the error:

> Msg 9437, Level 16, State 1, Line 11 XML parsing: line 5, character 46, duplicate attribute

Unsurprising, as if you look, the second `element` node has `attribute` declared twice.

---

So, how do you fix this?

Firstly, this means that you're storing your XML data as a datatype other than in an `xml` data type. XML should be stored using the `xml` data type (that's exactly what it's for), and only valid XML can be stored in it; as a result you wouldn't have been able to insert invalid XML into the row and wouldn't be in this position. As you are, there's only one thing you can do; find all the "bad" rows:

```
SELECT tank_inspection
FROM bulk_site_tank
WHERE TRY_CONVERT(xml,tank_inspection) IS NULL
  AND tank_inspection IS NOT NULL;
```

Then inspect every single row returned in the above dataset and fix the data. Make it valid XML. After that, fix your data type:

```
ALTER TABLE bulk_site_tank ALTER COLUMN tank_inspection xml;
```

Now everything is valid XML, you can fix that query of yours:

```
SELECT ship_to_cust_num,
       tank_num,
       tank_capacity_qty,
       tank_pkg_type_code,
       REPLACE(b.tank_inspection.value('(/TankInspection/Questions/Question[@AASAQno="9"]/@QAns)[1]', 'varchar(50)'), '#', '') --AS ?
FROM bulk_site_tank b
WHERE b.tank_inspection IS NOT NULL;
```

Note I change to `ANSI_NULL` syntax, and got rid of the `NOLOCK` (as I assume you don't know what it actually does here). The `CAST`/`CONVERT` expressions are gone too, and I've removed the `COALESCE`. As your `value` expression returns a `varchar(50)` and the `COALESCE` has a `0` for the second parameter. This would implicitly cast the value returned from the XML to an `int` and likely result in a conversion error.

I'm afraid it's up to you to clean up your data though, no one else can help you here I'm afraid. This is just one reason why poor data type choices is a problem; as if the correct data type was used then,as I said before, the invalid XML could never have been inserted.

Good luck!